# programmatically set room id in a Twilio conference

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, conference

Does anyone know the best way to programmatically set the name/id of the conference room in the Twilio noun ?

```
<Response>
    <Say>Joining a conference room</Say>
    <Dial>
        <Conference>MyRoom</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

My system will dole out new conference room ID's, dynamically, to keep the conferences small but I'm not sure how to associate the assigned user's room id in the to twiml app's code...

Comment: You will need to serve a dynamically generated Twiml, not a static one. You would call the TwiML with a parameter such as joinconference.php?room=98464. Your code then will then output the TwiML xml with the conference number used in the GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here. Wanted to add some example code for anyone who may stumble on this question.

You need to return [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) to give Twilio the instructions of what to do with a call but you can generate that TwiML however you'd like. For example, here is a simple PHP script that returns TwiML that places callers in a random conference room.

```
<?php
  header("content-type: text/xml");
  echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Say>Joining a conference room</Say>
    <Dial>
        <Conference>Room<?php echo rand(0,2); ?></Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```